# How to convert dictionary with list values to a table

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have dictionary:

```
{"A": [1,2,3], "B": [5,7,9], "C":[12,5,6]}
```

I would like it to be in the following format of a table:

```
A  |   1
A  |   2
A  |   3
B  |   5
B  |   7
.  |   .
.  |   .
C  |   6
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say *table*?

Comment: table as in table, I couldn't find how to represent it over here (however I have vaguely drawn it), but basically each row should have the key and one value from the list , then the next row key and one value from the list and so on..it doesn't need to have headers.

Comment: there are no *tables* in python. this is a data structure that simply does not exist. You can use `numpy` or `pandas` and construct a `matrix` or a `dataframe` respectively but even those are simply `nested lists`. What do you want to do with that?

Comment: yea, I meant dataframe or a prettytable or something like that.. but I wanted to know if there's a way to do what I'm asking...

Comment: Do you want just to print the result in that format or to store it somewhere? also, is the order in the first dictionary important for the result?

Comment: I want to store it to use it for classification purpose, order isn't important

Comment: @Murtuza_07 then i would go with a database. Look at `sqlite` and be more specifc next time please.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies guys, it's solved by Hulk :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {"A": [1,2,3], "B": [5,7,9], "C":[12,5,6]}
# make dictionary to list
l = []
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    temp = (key, value)
    l.append(temp)
# sort list
l = sorted(l, key = lambda x: x[0])
# finally!
for key, lists in l:
    for item in lists:
        print( "{}|{}".format(key, item) )
```

Comment: state that this is python 2 please. This code does not run in python3. `iteritems()` method has been renamed to just `items()`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need data presentation. There may be good different approach to
this.

Here is a simple python code to do that, see if it suits you need.

```
def dict_list_value_to_table(dict_with_list):
    """
    Function coverts a dictionary of list as it's 
    values to table format.
    >>> {"A": [1,2,3], "B": [5,7,9], "C":[12,5,6]}
    A  |  1
    A  |  2
    A  |  3
    B  |  5
    B  |  7
    B  |  9
    C  |  12
    C  |  5
    C  |  6

    """

    # Sorts the records orderly.
    for key in sorted(dict_with_list):
        for values in dict_with_list.get(key):
            print key, " | ", values 

    # Commented below does not sort.
    # But does the same.

    #for key, value in dict_with_list.items():
    #    for v in value:
    #        print key, "|",v  
    #        
    return 

if __name__=="__main__":
    arg = {"A": [1,2,3], "B": [5,7,9], "C":[12,5,6]}
    dict_list_value_to_table(arg)
```

If you want some thing advanced then, as suggested in the comment look for

**numpy** or **pandas** and other advanced python data structures.

Comment: Dictionaries will not have exact ordering

Answer (score 1):

use `OrderedDict` if you want elements in exact order they are added,

```
# tested in python2.7, 3.5

from collections import OrderedDict
data = {"A": [1,2,3], "B": [5,7,9], "C": [12,5,6]}
# expecting alpha order "A"
sorted_data = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda t: ord(t[0])))

for key, value in sorted_data.items():
    for le in value:
        print("{}|{}".format(key, le))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {"A": [1,2,3], "B": [5,7,9], "C":[12,5,6]}
for k,value in sorted(dict.items()):
  if isinstance(value, list):
     for v in sorted(value):
     # key and value are sorted
     print ("{0} | {1}".format(k, v))
```

output:

```
A | 1
A | 2
A | 3
B | 5
B | 7
B | 9
C | 5
C | 6
C | 12
```